# How do I sketch $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x}=x+\frac{1}{x}; g(x)=\sqrt{x-4};h(x)=(x+1)^2 -3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I sketch the following functions, applying appropriate transformations to the graphs of $y= \frac{1}{x} ,y= \sqrt x ,y=x^2$.

$$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x}=1+\frac{1}{x}; g(x)=\sqrt{x-4};h(x)=(x+1)^2 -3.$$

I am absolutely lost on this question and don't know where to start. Any help is very much appreciated :).

Comment: There is a typo in your function $f$.

Comment: A good way to get started may be looking at some examples. Have you seen any similar problems before from your notes/book?

Comment: I would say that $g$ and $h$ are the easiest, so maybe start with them (maybe $h$ being the easiest). You should try these and show your attempts at a solution and highlight where you are encountering specific problems. Hint: for $h$, can you graph $y=x^2$?

Comment: And indeed, $f(x)=\color{red}{1}+\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for notifying my of that typo. I'll fix it and I don't understand what it is meant when it says 'applying appropriate transformations to the graphs of ...'. Is it just referring to the functions?

Comment: Applying the transformations likely means you need to show the different transformations from the parent function to the desired function. For instance, the parent function of $h$ is the parabola given by $y=x^2$. The transformations applied in this case are changing $x^2$ to $(x+1)^2$ then to $(x+1)^2-3$; the former transformation shifts the graph to the left by $1$, and the latter transformation shifts the graph down by $3$.

Comment: You should also fix the typo in your title.

Answer (score 1):

The task is to look at the graphs of the functions $y=\frac{1}{x}$, $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=x^2$ and then modify them.

For example if we take $y=\sqrt{x}$. You can easily sketch the graph and now if you consider the function $g$, you just need to shift the graph by $4$ units to the right.

The same with other functions. The idea is just to start with the basic function and then sketch the graph of $f, g, h$ by applying some basic transformations (in the example - substracting a constant from the argument).

Answer (score 0):

1.for $f(x)$ first sketch the graph of $\dfrac{1}{x}$ then shift it 1 unit upward.
[image: graph of $\dfrac{1}{x}$]
[image: graph of $1+\dfrac{1}{x}$]

2.for $g(x)$ first sketch the graph of $\sqrt{x}$, then shift it 4 unit to the right.
[image: graph of $\sqrt{x}$]
[image: graph of $\sqrt{x-4}]

3.for $h(x)$ first sketch the graph of $x^2$ then shift it 1 unit to the left and then shift it 3 unit downward.
[image: graph of $x^2$]
[image: graph of $(x+1)^2$]
[image: graph of $(x+1)^2-3$]